# can not read/write data in function

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Hi i am use vue and axios for upload file

Does not recognize the list inside in onUploadProgress

code

```
data: ()=>({
        list: [
          { id:0, icon: 'image', iconClass: 'blue white--text', title: 'Vacation itinerary', file:"asasf.png", progress:100 },
          selectedFile: null
        ]
    }),
    methods:{
        async startUpload(){
            let formData = await new FormData();
            await formData.append('file', this.selectedFile);
            this.selectedFile=null

            let config = {
                onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent){
                    console.log(this.list) //is null
                    this.list[id].progress = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
                }
            };

            this.$axios.$post('/upload/insert', formData, config)
                .then(response => {
                    this.list[id].progress=100
                    this.list[id].file=response.data.path
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    }
```

console.log(this.list) in lone 16 is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `onUploadProgress` function to arrow function, otherwise `this` will be related to the context of `onUploadProgress` instead of the component.

```js
async startUpload(){
            let formData = await new FormData();
            await formData.append('file', this.selectedFile);
            this.selectedFile=null

            let config = {
                onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                    console.log(this.list) //is null
                    this.list[id].progress = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
                }
            };

            this.$axios.$post('/upload/insert', formData, config)
                .then(response => {
                    this.list[id].progress=100
                    this.list[id].file=response.data.path
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
```